# Simple jQuery toggle with bulma card not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bulma

I have a little bulma card. I tried to display it, when I click on the icon:

```
  <div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
      <p class="card-header-title">
        Component
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options" id="server">
        <span class="icon">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content is-hidden" id="server-content">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec iaculis mauris.
        <a href="#">@bulmaio</a>. <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
        <br>
        <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#server").click(function() {
    $("#server-content").toggle();
  });
});
```

But it didn't work. In my HTML Head I do this:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the main.js file is the snippet from above.
When I put an alert inside the jquery function it will be pop up, but the content is still hidden.

Comment: your code worked for me:- https://jsfiddle.net/tgwm93op/

Comment: Code is working as expected.

Comment: Noting wrong in your code. It is working

Comment: Remove `is-hidden` class from `<div class="card-content is-hidden" id="server-content">` and add `style="display: none;"`.

Comment: try adding this in head tag `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @NiK648 that was the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use jQuery's toggleClass function instead of toggle. is-hidden class in bulma will hide the div it is applied to. Please check at https://jsfiddle.net/rutsxz91/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#server").click(function() {
    $("#server-content").toggleClass('is-hidden');
  });
});
```